# Why are baseline hazard functions after Cox PH regression different in Stata and R

Tags: cox-model

I am a Stata user now teaching myself R. I have been trying to recapitulate analyses done in Stata using R but have got stuck. A multi-variable Cox regression with an offset in Stata and R give identical results
The data can be downloaded from

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r26sgzjy3rytw3r/test.csv?dl=0

Stata code

```
stset fu, failure(br)
stcox ag1 ag2 sz nd grade screen , offset(hc1) nohr
```

R-code
    library(survival)
    fit <- Surv(er1$fu, er1$br)
    mva <- coxph(fit ~ ag1 + ag2 + sz + nd + grade + screen +
                offset(hc1), data = er1)

However when I then derive the cumulative baseline hazard functions they are different.  This does not occur if I remove the offset term.

Stata code

```
predict h0, basechazard
twoway scatter h0 _t
```

R-code

```
h0 <- basehaz(mva, centered = F)
ggplot(data=h00, aes(x=time, y=hazard)) + geom_point()
```

[image: Stata]

[image: R cum baseline hazard]

Comment: You posted this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021000/why-the-estimate-of-the-cumulative-baseline-hazard-after-cox-ph-in-stata-differs  and got the good advice to try here. Fine, but https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic explains that cross-posting is not encouraged on SE. So, the implication is that you should post at just one site at once (and delete the post at the other). In either forum, the lack of a reproducible example is problematic, as we can't see your data. Experts in survival analysis (not me) may be able to help without it.

Comment: This question is quite interesting, I did some experiments, it is true, when there are no offset variables, the baseline cumulative hazards are the same for STATA and R (using same methods to handle ties), when there are the offset varialbes, the  baseline cumulative hazards are quite different from the two software.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you. I had not realised cross-posting was frowned upon.  I am not sure how to add the data file on which the analysis is based.

Comment: In this particular case, a reproducible example should be possible, I imagine, with a simpler dataset invented for the purpose. The bigger deal is someone seeing this who understands exactly how offsets are handled in both programs, not me, and so far no takers.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but in case someone ends up here looking for the answer:

By default, `survival::coxph` demeans any non-binary covariates (and any offsets, regardless of their measurement level), to make any baseline cumulative hazard/survivor estimates from `survival::survfit` more stable.  (`survival::basehaz` is a wrapper for `survival::survfit`.)  By contrast, Stata's `stcox` does not demean its covariates.

Demeaning doesn't affect the coefficient estimates.  That's why R's and Stata's Cox model output still matches, provided you use the same tie correction method.  Stata's default (`breslow`) is not R's default (`efron`).

For more on `coxph`'s demeaning behavior, see the second paragraph under the "Details" section of `coxph`'s help file (`survival 3.3-1`).  See also the `nocenter` option in that help file, which affects only covariates, not offsets.

### MWE

#### Stata

```
// (picking female as offset, arbitrarily)
* not demeaned
webuse catheter, clear
stcox age, offset(female) efron
predict double H0, basec            // WON'T MATCH R

* demeaned
foreach x of varlist age female{
    sum `x' if(e(sample)==1)
    gen double `x'_dem = `x' - `r(mean)'
}
stcox age_dem, offset(female_dem) efron
predict double H0_dem, basec        // WILL MATCH R

* print the quantities
bysort _t: gen flag = _n==1
list _t H0* if(flag==1), noobs

    ** (INSERTED THE OUTPUT)
    +-----------------------------+
    |  _t          H0      H0_dem |
    |-----------------------------|
    |   2   .00442489   .01208141 |
    |   4   .00442489   .01208141 |
    |   5   .00442489   .01208141 |
    |   6   .00442489   .01208141 |
    |   7   .01390727   .03797142 |
    |-----------------------------|
    |   8    .0236089   .06446007 |
    |   9   .02865578   .07823973 |
    |  12   .03885037    .1060743 |
    |  13   .04399411    .1201184 |
    |  15   .05477359   .14954993 |
    |-----------------------------|
    |  16   .06027266   .16456422 |
    |  17   .06591772   .17997709 |
    |  22   .07160917   .19551662 |
    |  23   .07746653   .21150915 |
    |  24   .08345176   .22785078 |
    |-----------------------------|
    |  25   .08967049   .24482998 |
    |  26   .09606417   .26228683 |
    |  27   .10261635   .28017644 |
    |  28    .1093372   .29852657 |
    |  30   .13734608   .37500003 |
    |-----------------------------|
    |  33   .14474793   .39520951 |
    |  34   .15235003   .41596575 |
    |  38   .16017444   .43732899 |
    |  39   .16821064   .45927044 |
    |  40    .1764812    .4818518 |
    |-----------------------------|
    |  43   .18484174   .50467883 |
    |  46   .18484174   .50467883 |
    |  53   .19374013   .52897436 |
    |  54   .19374013   .52897436 |
    |  58   .20328969   .55504782 |
    |-----------------------------|
    |  63   .21320181   .58211117 |
    |  66   .22325786    .6095675 |
    |  70   .22325786    .6095675 |
    |  78   .23413436   .63926391 |
    |  96   .24547173   .67021867 |
    |-----------------------------|
    | 108   .24547173   .67021867 |
    | 113   .24547173   .67021867 |
    | 114   .25838971   .70548901 |
    | 119   .27192819   .74245352 |
    | 130   .28606182   .78104298 |
    |-----------------------------|
    | 132   .30099395   .82181262 |
    | 141   .31659951   .86442093 |
    | 149   .31659951   .86442093 |
    | 152   .35238347   .96212294 |
    | 154   .37160181   1.0145953 |
    |-----------------------------|
    | 156   .39134013   1.0684874 |
    | 159   .39134013   1.0684874 |
    | 177   .41406096   1.1305228 |
    | 185   .43900652   1.1986324 |
    | 190   .46665975   1.2741348 |
    |-----------------------------|
    | 196   .49734176   1.3579068 |
    | 201   .53249754   1.4538937 |
    | 245    .5731822   1.5649762 |
    | 292   .61953858   1.6915444 |
    | 318   .67502001    1.843027 |
    |-----------------------------|
    | 402   .74292041   2.0284174 |
    | 447   .83017281   2.2666452 |
    | 511   .95265565   2.6010637 |
    | 536   1.1827563   3.2293142 |
    | 562   1.9349645   5.2830905 |
    +-----------------------------+
```

#### R

```R
library(survival)  # 3.3-1
library(broom)     # 1.0.0

# Load data
cath <- haven::read_dta("https://www.stata-press.com/data/r17/catheter.dta")

# Est model
mod <- coxph(Surv(`_t0`, `_t`, `_d`) ~ age + offset(female), data=cath)

# Get H0
sf.mod <- survfit(mod)

# Get into df for easy viewing
sf.mod.df <- tidy(sf.mod)
sf.mod.df$estimate <- sf.mod$cumhaz

# Print
print(as.data.frame(sf.mod.df[,c("time","estimate")]),
      digits=7,
      row.names=FALSE)

## (INSERTED THE OUTPUT)
time   estimate
   2 0.01208141
   4 0.01208141
   5 0.01208141
   6 0.01208141
   7 0.03797142
   8 0.06446007
   9 0.07823973
  12 0.10607430
  13 0.12011840
  15 0.14954993
  16 0.16456422
  17 0.17997709
  22 0.19551662
  23 0.21150915
  24 0.22785078
  25 0.24482998
  26 0.26228683
  27 0.28017644
  28 0.29852657
  30 0.37500003
  33 0.39520951
  34 0.41596575
  38 0.43732899
  39 0.45927044
  40 0.48185180
  43 0.50467883
  46 0.50467883
  53 0.52897436
  54 0.52897436
  58 0.55504782
  63 0.58211117
  66 0.60956750
  70 0.60956750
  78 0.63926391
  96 0.67021867
 108 0.67021867
 113 0.67021867
 114 0.70548901
 119 0.74245352
 130 0.78104298
 132 0.82181262
 141 0.86442093
 149 0.86442093
 152 0.96212294
 154 1.01459533
 156 1.06848744
 159 1.06848744
 177 1.13052280
 185 1.19863239
 190 1.27413483
 196 1.35790683
 201 1.45389369
 245 1.56497621
 292 1.69154439
 318 1.84302697
 402 2.02841741
 447 2.26664521
 511 2.60106372
 536 3.22931416
 562 5.28309054
```